# iOS Tolo bus REGISTER() macro wierd behavior

Tags: ios

I have an ordinary Database manager class. Here is the code:

```
#import "DatabaseManager.h"
#import "Tolo.h"
#import "Action.h"
#import "ActionCreatorConstants.h"
#import <sqlite3.h>
#import "DatabaseConstants.h"
#import "KGKSignal.h"

@interface DatabaseManager ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *documentsDirectory;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *databaseFilename;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *arrayResults;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *arrayColumnNames;
@property (nonatomic) int affectedRows;
@property (nonatomic) long long lastInsertedRowID;

@end

@implementation DatabaseManager

static DatabaseManager *instance = nil;

+ (instancetype)getInstance {
    if (instance == nil) {
        instance = [[DatabaseManager alloc] initWithDatabaseFilename:DATABASE_NAME];
    }
    return instance;
}

- (instancetype)initWithDatabaseFilename:(NSString *)databaseFilename {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        REGISTER();

        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        self.documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        self.databaseFilename = databaseFilename;
        // [self copyDatabaseIntoDocumentsDirectory];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)copyDatabaseIntoDocumentsDirectory {
    NSString *destinationPath = [self.documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:self.databaseFilename];
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:destinationPath]) {
        NSString *sourcePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:self.databaseFilename];
        NSError *error;
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:sourcePath
                                                toPath:destinationPath
                                                 error:&error];
        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }
}

- (void)runQuery:(const char *)query isQueryExecutable:(BOOL)queryExecutable {
    sqlite3 *sqlite3Database;
//    NSString *databasePath = [self.documentsDirectory
//                              stringByAppendingPathComponent:self.databaseFilename];
    NSString *databasePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:DATABASE_NAME];
    if (self.arrayResults != nil) {
        [self.arrayResults removeAllObjects];
        self.arrayResults = nil;
    }
    self.arrayResults = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    if (self.arrayColumnNames != nil) {
        [self.arrayColumnNames removeAllObjects];
        self.arrayColumnNames = nil;
    }
    self.arrayColumnNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    BOOL openDatabaseResult = sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &sqlite3Database);
    if (openDatabaseResult == SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

        BOOL preparedStatementResult = sqlite3_prepare_v2(sqlite3Database, query, -1,
                                                      &compiledStatement, NULL);
        if (preparedStatementResult == SQLITE_OK) {
            if (!queryExecutable) {
                NSMutableArray *arrayDataRow;

                while (sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                    arrayDataRow = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                    int totalColumns = sqlite3_column_count(compiledStatement);

                    for (int i = 0; i < totalColumns; i++) {
                        char *dbDataAsChars = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, i);
                        if (dbDataAsChars != NULL) {
                            [arrayDataRow addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:dbDataAsChars]];
                        }

                        if (self.arrayColumnNames.count != totalColumns) {
                            dbDataAsChars = (char *)sqlite3_column_name(compiledStatement, i);
                            [self.arrayColumnNames addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:dbDataAsChars]];
                        }
                    }

                    if (arrayDataRow.count > 0) {
                        [self.arrayResults addObject:arrayDataRow];
                    }
                }
            } else {
                BOOL executeQueryResult = sqlite3_step(compiledStatement);
                if (executeQueryResult) {
                    self.affectedRows = sqlite3_changes(sqlite3Database);
                    self.lastInsertedRowID = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(sqlite3Database);
                } else {
                    NSLog(@"Database error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(sqlite3Database));
                }
            }
        } else {
           NSLog(@"%s", sqlite3_errmsg(sqlite3Database));
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
    }
    sqlite3_close(sqlite3Database);
}

- (NSArray *)loadDataFromDatabase:(NSString *)query {
    [self runQuery:[query UTF8String] isQueryExecutable:NO];
    return (NSArray *)self.arrayResults;
}

- (void)executeQuery:(NSString *)query {
    [self runQuery:[query UTF8String] isQueryExecutable:YES];
}

SUBSCRIBE(Action) {
    if ([event.type isEqualToString:GET_LAST_SIGNAL_DATE_FROM_DATABASE]) {
        NSLog(@"Lal");
    }
}

- (void)insertSignal:(KGKSignal *)signal {
    NSString *insertSignalQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO %@ (%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@) VALUES (%ld,%ld,%f,%f,%ld,%f,%f,%ld,%ld,%ld,%ld,%ld);", TABLE_SIGNAL, COLUMN_DEVICE_ID, COLUMN_MODE, COLUMN_LATITUDE, COLUMN_LONGITUDE, COLUMN_DATE, COLUMN_VOLTAGE, COLUMN_BALANCE, COLUMN_SATELLITES, COLUMN_SPEED, COLUMN_CHARGE, COLUMN_DIRECTION, COLUMN_TEMPERATURE, (long)signal.deviceId, (long)signal.mode, signal.latitude, signal.longitude, (long)signal.date, signal.voltage, signal.balance, (long)signal.satellites, (long)signal.speed, (long)signal.charge, (long)signal.direction, (long)signal.temperature];
    [self executeQuery:insertSignalQuery];
}

- (NSInteger)getLastSignalDate {
    NSInteger lastSignalDate = 1441065600;
    return lastSignalDate;
}

@end
```

The problem lurks in the last method - getLastSignalDate. When i set return value to 0 - app works ok. When method returns any non-null number - app craches in runtime (build successful). Error occurs in Tolo object - it can not register (Via REGISTER() macro) Database Manager object - EXC_BAD_ACCESS error in publish method of Tolo.m. Did someone face with same wierd behavior???

I've overriden dealloc method of Database Manager and it didn't log before error occured - so object exists in memory.

Comment: A web search for `getLastSignalDate` only turned up this question, so I've got no idea what signature the method should have. But judging from the name, is it possible that the return value should be an `NSDate *` instead of an `NSInteger`? In that case, the crash would be pretty obvious since it's very unlikely that the returned integer points to a valid object.

Comment: It's my own custom method - i've tried a few return types but NSInteger should work well with numbers - suppose return date in Uniox seconds. I can say that this method don't even get called in runtime.

Comment: So, where does the debugger say the crash is occurring? Please post a stack trace or a screenshot of the stack trace.

Comment: Some new details: when i changed name of the method from "getLastSignalDate" to "gtLastSignalDate" - app run ok. I think Tolo interpret get... methods a bit wrong or something...